# Selenium return empty list from morningstar

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to extract info from morningstar but driver return back a list empty.

here's the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import datetime
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome(<<...>>)
driver.implicitly_wait(1)
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get('https://www.morningstar.it/it/etf/snapshot/snapshot.aspx?id=0P0001J2VK&tab=3&InvestmentType=FE')
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_id("individualinvestor").click()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_id("_evidon-accept-button").click()
time.sleep(1)

usStock=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="sal-asset-allocation__assetTableRow sal-asset-allocation__assetTableRow--usStock"]/td[2]')
```

thx

Answer (score 0):

That is because it is in iframe, so you need to switch it first like this :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "portfolio")))
usStock = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="sal-asset-allocation__assetTableRow sal-asset-allocation__assetTableRow--usStock"]/td[2]')
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

also, I would scrape it like this (since time.sleep() is not recommended at all) so you can use Explicit wait like this :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get("https://www.morningstar.it/it/etf/snapshot/snapshot.aspx?id=0P0001J2VK&tab=3&InvestmentType=FE")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "individualinvestor"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "_evidon-accept-button"))).click()
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "portfolio")))
usStock = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("tr[class*='al-asset-allocation'] td")
print(len(usStock))
for stock in usStock:
    print(stock.text)
```

Comment: thanks for the support! Anyway,
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "portfolio")))
return me back error:
StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.131)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 10.0.19043 x86_64)

that's only my problem?

Comment: Did you run the whole code which I have given you ? It worked for me.

Comment: Error is strange. Your code works but it seems that driver don't wait for 20 second. Not sure why they give me back an error. After that error if i try to switch to the frame and use the selector code works.

Comment: No it wouldn't wait for 20 seconds, it's an explicit wait and it's dynamic in nature. It will only wait for element to be found. What is the error by the way ?

Comment: StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document (Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.131) (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 10.0.19043 x86_64)